# Visual Studio not stopping at break points put up on javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I'm trying to debug javascript code in a MVC 4.5 application using visual studio 2012 and internet explorer 10 but visual studio doesn't break on my set breakpoints.

I enabled script debugging in IE and restarted, is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Using firebug kind of tools may also help in debugging JavaScript. However it will allow you to debug only JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My javascript was contained within my view, moving the code to an external js file seemed to do the trick.